# ccrpDtp.ocx error while running vb6 project in windows 7

Tags: dll, windows-7, vb6, ocx

I got the following error while running the vb6 project in windows 7. I was search in google. I can't find the exact solution. Please help me to fix this issues.

```
The component CCrpDtp.ocx or one of its dependencies not correctly registered.a file is missing or invalid
```

Comment: Run regedit.exe and open HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  Do a search for your file name.  If it isn't there, see if you have it on your disk.  If you do, then use regsvr32.exe to register it.  If you don't, then follow C-Pound Guru's instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing is to check to see if you have the ccrpdtp.ocx file installed and registered on your machine.

If you do not, go to the [Common Controls Replacement Project](http://ccrp.mvps.org/) site and download `ccrpdtp6.zip`.

The file contains the control and a dll dependency, both of which need to be installed somewhere on your machine. There's also a readme file which explains that you have to use [regsvr32](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx) to register the ocx.